# binding a port number to a TCP socket (outgoin) to send packets

Tags: c++, c, networking, tcp, network-programming

I know that it is not easy to **bind a port number** to **TCP socket** that you would use to **send data** (because systems usually bind a random port to sockets).

But I read on one article that by using some **low level networking** methods you can bind a port number to a TCP socket then use it to send data ?

Does anyone has an idea about how that could be done ?

I am using c programming language

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204169/how-to-create-a-tcp-socket-connect-using-c-to-a-predefined-port

Comment: The reasons for wanting to do this at all are usually spurious.

Comment: I want to do a port prediction, (because my NAT box don't use port preservation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bind it before connecting.

```
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
/* ... */

memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));
client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
client_addr.sin_port = htons(22222);

if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, sizeof(client_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

connect(s, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
```

Comment: then, will I able to listen through same port(in this case 22222) also? I think NO. but please confirm.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is quite easy. Simply use the [bind](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bind.html) function as you would for a server.

Comment: then, will I able to listen through same port also? I think NO. but please confirm.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply call `bind()` before `connect()` in a client in the same way that you would call `bind()` before `listen()` in a server.  There is nothing more complicated to it than that.

Comment: then, will I able to listen through same port(in this case 22222) also? I think NO. but please confirm.