# Force an application to use a specific source port on a fedora machine

Tags: linux, fedora

I have an application on my fedora machine that sends SIP requests to the server. The application chooses a random source port to send the requests. Is there some way I can force the application to use a specific port (say 15000). Can I, maybe, block the application from using all other ports (and then it will have to choose a single source port)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind before connect or send.  See here:

[binding a port number to a TCP socket (outgoin) to send packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468113/binding-a-port-number-to-a-tcp-socket-outgoin-to-send-packets)

I think it works the same for UDP.

Comment: I cannot change the SIP application. It sends SIP requests over TCP, and for the source port the application will choose a random port which is not configurable by any option. But I need the application to choose a specific port. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: If you aren't allowed to change the code, then this is not a programming question.  I suggest you take it to SuperUser.